# Jenkins non blocking triggered projects

Tags: jenkins

We have a parent build which triggers multiple child builds. Now all the child builds are blocking as shown below:-

[image]

Is there a way we can make some of the child builds non-blocking (may be by some callback means or some other) and also get the status of the child build in parent build?